# tinymce formatter apply inline getNode refresh

Tags: javascript, tinymce

There are places that I do not know by adding a node with tinyMCE.

Added processing to expand the space between characters by pressing "+" button.

```
editor.addButton('lsplus', {
text: '+',
tooltip: 'letter-spacing +',
icon: false,
onclick: function () {
    var currentFontSize = 0;
    if ($(tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode()).css('letter-spacing')) {
        currentFontSize = new Number($(tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode())
            .css('letter-spacing').replace('px', ''));
    }
    currentFontSize = currentFontSize + 1;
    tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.register('lsplus', {
        inline : 'span',
        styles: { 'letter-spacing': currentFontSize + 'px' }
    });
    tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.apply('lsplus');
}
```

});

For example,

```
<p>abc-de-fg</p>
```

Suppose there was a block this.
Select "de" and press the "+" button.
Then the first one moves normally. It will be as follows.

```
<p>abc-<span style="letter-spacing: 1px;">de</span>-fg</p>
```

However, without changing the selected state as it is
Press the "+" button again.

For selection

```
<p>abc-<span style="letter-spacing: 1px;">de</span>-fg</p>
```

Because it is as described above, p tag is left as it is in node acquisition after the second time.

When you remove the cursor and select "de" again,
Since the span tag is set for selection, there is nothing wrong with it
I want to set the node that added and applied to selection so that I can press the button continuously
What should I do?

```
<span style="letter-spacing: 1px;">de</span>
```

best regard.

Comment: I've just answered this for someone else here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898296/custom-tinymce-4-x-button-to-increase-letter-spacing-not-working

Comment: Hi K Scandrett.
I have looked at your answer.
There was an answer I was seeking and it was helpful.
Thank you! I am grateful.