# Custom TinyMCE 4.x button to increase letter spacing not working

Tags: tinymce-4

I implemented a TinyMCE button to increase the letter spacing at http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Z9eaab/31. If you enter the words "some text" in the text area at the bottom and then select "some" and hit the "Increase letter spacing" button multiple times, the letter spacing only increases the first time. If you select the second word, "text," the spacing increases each time you hit "Increase letter spacing." as it should.

I can see from the console.log on line 9 that when it doesn't work it's because the current spacing read doesn't reflect the last increase, so it just keeps redoing the first one.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  tinymce.PluginManager.add('example', function(editor, url) {
    // Add a button that opens a window
    editor.addButton('example1', {
      text: 'Increase letter spacing',
      icon: false,
      onclick: function() {
        var currentSpacing = new Number($(tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode()).css('letter-spacing').replace('px', ''));
        console.log("spacing read is" + currentSpacing);
        currentSpacing = currentSpacing + 1;

        tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.register('increaseSpacing', {
          inline: 'span',
          styles: {
            'letter-spacing': currentSpacing + 'px'
          }
        });

        tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.apply('increaseSpacing');
      }
    });

    editor.addButton('example2', {
      text: 'Decrease letter spacing',
      icon: false,
      onclick: function() {
        var currentSpacing = new Number($(tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode()).css('letter-spacing').replace('px', ''));
        currentSpacing = currentSpacing - 1;

        tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.register('decreaseSpacing', {
          inline: 'span',
          styles: {
            'letter-spacing': currentSpacing + 'px'
          }
        });

        tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.apply('decreaseSpacing');
      }
    });

    // Adds a menu item to the tools menu
    editor.addMenuItem('example', {
      text: 'Example plugin',
      context: 'tools',
      onclick: function() {
        // Open window with a specific url
        editor.windowManager.open({
          title: 'TinyMCE site',
          url: 'http://www.tinymce.com',
          width: 400,
          height: 300,
          buttons: [{
            text: 'Close',
            onclick: 'close'
          }]
        });
      }
    });
  });

  tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: "example",
    toolbar: "example1 example2 undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
  });
</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
  <textarea name="content"></textarea>
</form>
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `selection.getNode()` which finds the common parent node of the start and end points of the selection. This is *not* the node that is in the current selection.

In your case you want the `<span>` you've created, but what you've actually asked for is its enclosing `<p>` (subsequently you're checking its current `letter-spacing` CSS value, which it won't have).

To correct this, after applying the formatting, grab the span (either created previously, or newly added), and set the current selection to it. You can do this using [`selection.getStart()`](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce.dom/tinymce.dom.selection/#getstart):

```
var spanNode = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getStart();
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.select(spanNode);
```

When used after the `tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.apply()`, it will be the correct span.

Here's the updated code (I've made a number of other formatting changes):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  tinymce.PluginManager.add('example', function(editor, url) {
    // Add a button that opens a window
    editor.addButton('example1', {
      text: 'Increase letter spacing',
      icon: false,
      onclick: function() {

        var currentSpacing = 0;
        var $selectedContent = $(tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent({'format': 'html'}));

        if ($selectedContent.is("span") && $selectedContent.css('letter-spacing')) {
          currentSpacing = +($selectedContent.css('letter-spacing').replace('px', ''));
        }

        currentSpacing += 1;

        tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.apply('letterSpacing', {
          value: currentSpacing + 'px'
        });

        var spanNode = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getStart();
        tinymce.activeEditor.selection.select(spanNode);

      }
    });

    editor.addButton('example2', {
      text: 'Decrease letter spacing',
      icon: false,
      onclick: function() {

        var currentSpacing = 0;
        var $selectedContent = $(tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent({'format': 'html'}));

        if ($selectedContent.is("span") && $selectedContent.css('letter-spacing')) {
          currentSpacing = +($selectedContent.css('letter-spacing').replace('px', ''));
        }

        currentSpacing -= 1;

        tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.apply('letterSpacing', {
          value: currentSpacing + 'px'
        });

        var spanNode = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getStart();
        tinymce.activeEditor.selection.select(spanNode);

      }
    });

    // Adds a menu item to the tools menu
    editor.addMenuItem('example', {
      text: 'Example plugin',
      context: 'tools',
      onclick: function() {
        // Open window with a specific url
        editor.windowManager.open({
          title: 'TinyMCE site',
          url: 'http://www.tinymce.com',
          width: 400,
          height: 300,
          buttons: [{
            text: 'Close',
            onclick: 'close'
          }]
        });
      }
    });
  });

  tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: "example",
    toolbar: "example1 example2 undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    formats: {
      'letterSpacing': {
        inline: 'span',
        styles: {
          'letter-spacing': '%value'
        }
      }
    }
  });
</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
  <textarea name="content"></textarea>
</form>
```

Demo: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/wYfaab/2

Comment: You'll notice that I moved the registered formatter declaration to the `tinymce.init` section to improve performance - so it doesn't try to re-register with every button click. I pass the dynamic value in the `formatter.apply()` call. You may like to consider extracting the common code from the incr / decr functions. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For me, made some changes on the code above and this works.

Change this:

```
 tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.apply('letterSpacing', {
      value: currentSpacing + 'px'
    });
```

For this:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.register('mycustomformat', {
       inline: 'span',
       styles: {'letterSpacing': currentSpacing+'px'}
     });
tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.apply('mycustomformat');
```

Complete script:

```html
<script>
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('example', function(editor, url) {
        // Add a button that opens a window
        editor.addButton('example1', {
          text: 'Increase letter spacing',
          icon: false,
          onclick: function() {
    
            var currentSpacing = 0;
            var $selectedContent = $(tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent({'format': 'html'}));
    
            
            
            if ($selectedContent.is("span") && $selectedContent.css('letter-spacing')) {
              currentSpacing = +($selectedContent.css('letter-spacing').replace('px', ''));
            }
            currentSpacing += 1;
            
            tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.register('mycustomformat', {
               inline: 'span',
               styles: {'letterSpacing': currentSpacing+'px'}
             });
            tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.apply('mycustomformat');
            
            var spanNode = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getStart();
            tinymce.activeEditor.selection.select(spanNode);
    
          }
        });
    
        editor.addButton('example2', {
          text: 'Decrease letter spacing',
          icon: false,
          onclick: function() {
    
            var currentSpacing = 0;
            var $selectedContent = $(tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent({'format': 'html'}));
    
            if ($selectedContent.is("span") && $selectedContent.css('letter-spacing')) {
              currentSpacing = +($selectedContent.css('letter-spacing').replace('px', ''));
            }
    
            currentSpacing -= 1;
    
            tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.register('mycustomformat2', {
               inline: 'span',
               styles: {'letterSpacing': currentSpacing+'px'}
             });
            tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.apply('mycustomformat2');
    
            var spanNode = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getStart();
            tinymce.activeEditor.selection.select(spanNode);
    
          }
        });
    
        // Adds a menu item to the tools menu
        editor.addMenuItem('example', {
          text: 'Example plugin',
          context: 'tools',
          onclick: function() {
            // Open window with a specific url
            editor.windowManager.open({
              title: 'TinyMCE site',
              url: 'http://www.tinymce.com',
              width: 400,
              height: 300,
              buttons: [{
                text: 'Close',
                onclick: 'close'
              }]
            });
          }
        });
    });
    
    
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        plugins: "example",
        toolbar: "example1 example2 undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        formats: {
          'letterSpacing': {
            inline: 'span',
            styles: {
              'letter-spacing': '%value'
            }
          }
        }
      });
    
   </script>
<form method="post" action="dump.php">
  <textarea name="content"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: It would be helpful for the OP if you explain the changes you have made.